# C# system tray context menu showing below the icon

Tags: c#, windows, contextmenu, system-tray

I have a Windows Application that I have created that utilizes the system tray to "hold" the application when it is open and running behind the scenes. However, the popup context menu that I created for it (used Infragistics UltraToolbarsManager), the menu appears but below the icon cutting off most of the menu.

How do I rectify this problem?

Comment: Are there any particluar reason why you cannot use the regular ContextMenuStrip? That way it works directly.

Comment: The Infragistics UltraToolsbarsManager has a popup context menu that I can reference directly from the NotifyIcon control (it looks nicer as well; appearance is everything to the head honchos here). 

Im gonna try the plain contextmenustrip and see if that makes any difference,

Comment: The plain ContextMenuStrip will always scroll up if scrolling down would place part of it below the bottom of the screen. This is fairly basic functionality I would have thought...

Comment: Ok using the ContextMenuStrip worked and it actually looks better than I thought it would, thank you danbystrom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the ContextMenuStrip, this was resolved